# how to search string in listdir in any variation

Tags: python, listdir

I want to understand how to search for filenames regardless of case level or variation. 
It seems like the listdir method only accepts the exact name.

For example:

file path: C:\user\files\Hello file

this works

- searching the string 'Hello' will return C:\user\files\Hello file

this does not

- searching the string 'HELLO' or any other variation (in caps) will
  return     nothing

is there a work around to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `re` like,

```
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir('.') # listing the files for demonstration
['hello', 'foo.zip', 'Hello']
>>> import re, glob
# search for file ending with `hello`,
>>> [f for f in os.listdir('.') if re.search('hello$', f, flags=re.IGNORECASE)]
['hello', 'Hello']
```